# Erro "Já existe um elemento de gráfico com o nome '0' em 'SeriesCollection'"

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo um programa para fazer a limiarização de imagens, e queria mostrar um gráfico com que tons de cinza mais aparecem na imagem. Na primeira vez o programa funciona normal, porém na segunda ele da esse erro:

> "Já existe um elemento de gráfico com o nome '0' em 'SeriesCollection'"

Eu já tentei usar o `Grafico.Series.Clear();` e diversos outros tipos de código para limpar o gráfico mas nada adiantou.

Esse é meu main atual:

```
    private Image imagem;
    private Image cinza;
    Series seri;
    Color corlabel;
    Ocorrencia cla = new Ocorrencia();
    bool rad;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void salvarImagemToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "Images|*.bmp;";

            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(sfd.FileName);

                PBS.Image.Save(sfd.FileName);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro ao salvar a imagem tente novamente");
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void carregarImagemToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        corlabel = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);

        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Title = "Selecione um arquivo de imagem";
        dialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
        dialog.Filter = "Imagens(*.bmp; *.jpg; *.gif)|*.bmp; *.jpg; *.gif | Todos os Arquivos(*.*)| *.*";
        dialog.RestoreDirectory = false;

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            imagem = Image.FromFile(dialog.FileName);
            PBC.Image = Image.FromFile(dialog.FileName);

            /// Fazendo imagem em tons de cinza 
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.ForeColor = corlabel;
        label2.Text = "Em processo";

        cinza = (Image)imagem.Clone();

        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(cinza);

        Bitmap imgc = cla.Monocromatico(img);

        PBM.Image = imgc;

        this.Refresh();

        List<Ocorrencia> lista = cla.ContarOcorrencias(img);

        /// jogando no grafico

        lista = lista.OrderBy(x => x.Quantidade).ToList();

        Grafico.Legends[0].LegendStyle = LegendStyle.Table;


        int[] seriesArray = new int[lista.Count];

        int[] pointsArray = new int[lista.Count];


        int i = 0;
        foreach (Ocorrencia o in lista)
        {
            seriesArray[i++] = o.Cor;
        }

        i = 0;
        foreach (Ocorrencia o in lista)
        {
            pointsArray[i++] = o.Quantidade;
        }

            Grafico.Series.Clear();

        for (int ib = 0; ib < lista.Count; ib++)
        {
            // ERRO -> linha em que o erro aparece
            seri = Grafico.Series.Add(Convert.ToString(seriesArray[ib])); 
            seri.Points.Add((pointsArray[ib]));
        }

        int limiar = cla.CalcularLimiar(lista);

        LBLimiar.Text = Convert.ToString(limiar);

        if (radioButton1.Checked == true) {
            rad = true;
        } else {
            rad = false;
        }

        Bitmap imgl = cla.Limiarizacao(img, limiar,rad);

        PBS.Image = img;

        corlabel = Color.FromArgb(50, 205, 50);
        label2.ForeColor = corlabel;
        label2.Text = "Concluido";
    }

    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Esse `SeriesCollection` do erro é a classe `Chart.SeriesCollection` (Excel?)? Essa classe `Series` é sua? Se sim, qual o código dela?

Comment: @PedroGaspar Eu não tenho certeza, mas quando pesquisei para arrumar esse erro encontrei as pessoas relacionando os dois. Essa Classe `Series` é do próprio c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui identificar que você está usando o controle `Chart` da biblioteca Windows Forms ([documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart)), e vi que o método `SeriesCollection.Add()` que você está usando recebe um `String` com o nome do objeto `Series` que está sendo adicionado ([documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.seriescollection.add?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

Você está percorrendo o array `int[] seriesArray` para adicionar os objetos `Series` à coleção, e está usando o valor desse array para dar o nome ao objeto `Series` sendo criado. Muito provavelmente você tem o valor zero (0) mais de uma vez no array, por isso ele cria o primeiro objeto `Series` com nome "0", mas na segunda vez que encontra um zero, ele diz que o nome já existe.

Você pode usar o índice do array, por exemplo, para nomear o objeto `Series`, dessa forma creio que você não terá problemas:

```
for (int ib = 0; ib < lista.Count; ib++)
{
   seri = Grafico.Series.Add(Convert.ToString(ib)); 
   seri.Points.Add((pointsArray[ib]));
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente não posso usar desse jeito pois cada numero de 0255 representa uma cor na escala de cinza e quando eu ordeno a lista, o numero da cor tem que acompanhar quantas vezes ela aparece. Não teria algum jeito de limpar os dados do gráfico? dei uma olhada na documentação mas não encontrei um jeito, e pelo visto o `Grafico.Series.Clear();`

Comment: Você tem que achar uma forma de dar nomes únicos a esses objetos, porque nomes repetidos não serão aceitos. Você usa esse nome depois para acessar os objetos da coleção (`SeriesCollection`)?